# Insert result of the function to div attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm completely new to HTML and JavaScript. I need to use 3Dmol.js so I followed the tutorial and I have a working piece of code:

```html
<script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js"></script>

<div id="element1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; position: relative;" class='viewer_3Dmoljs' data-pdb='1a5j' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='cartoon' data-select1='resi:10' data-style1='stick:color=0x00FFFF'>
</div>
```

I would like to run a function that returns some value and puts it in data-select1='resi:x', where x is this value.

```
<script> 
    function a(x) {
    return x;
}
</script>
```

So if I run:

```
a(2);
```

The div changes to:

```html
   <script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js"></script>

    <div id="element1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; position: relative;" class='viewer_3Dmoljs' data-pdb='1a5j' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='cartoon' data-select1='resi:2' data-style1='stick:color=0x00FFFF'>
    </div>
```

What's the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) to set the `data-select1` attribute

```js
function a(x) {

    var el = document.getElementById('element1')
 
    // will set `data-select1`
    el.dataset.select1 = 'resi:'+x

    return x;
}

a(2);
```

```html
<script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js"></script>

<div id="element1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; position: relative;" class='viewer_3Dmoljs' data-pdb='1a5j' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='cartoon' data-select1='resi:10' data-style1='stick:color=0x00FFFF'>
</div>
```

Comment: So the function should be placed in some script.js file and the html chunk inside .html file?

Comment: Well you can run JavaScript inside your HTML if you want using <script></script> tags

Comment: Ok, so then the function call, I mean a(2); should be done inside <script></script> tags as well?

Comment: Yes, mostly. Except, I would assume `a(2)` should be called from some action. Or else you could just set the element correctly upon load

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `dataset`.

```
function a(x){
  var element1 = document.getElemenyById('element1');
  if (element1) element1.dataset.select1 = "resi:" + x;
}
```

An alternative if you need to support IE 8+ is going directly through `setAttribute`. Check browser compatibility on dataset [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset).

```
function a(x){
  var element1 = document.getElemenyById('element1');
  if (element1) element1.setAttribute("data-select1:", "resi:" + x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script> 
    function a(x) {
       $('#element1').data('select1','resi:'+x);
       console.log($('#element1').data('select1'));
}
</script>
```

Comment: This assumes the person is using jQuery 

Comment: That's true @KevinJantzer. For a pure js solution I agree with the one you provided

Answer (score 1):

Dataset is awesome, but browser support is only so so. You can also use `getAttribute()`. I borrowed some of @Kevin Jantzer's code (I can't leave comments yet lol).

```js
function a(x) {

    var el = document.getElementById('element1');
 
    // will set `data-select1`
    el.getAttribute('data-select1' == 'resi:' + x);

    return x;
}

console.log(a(2));
```

```html
<script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js"></script>

<div id="element1" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; position: relative;" class='viewer_3Dmoljs' data-pdb='1a5j' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='cartoon' data-select1='resi:10' data-style1='stick:color=0x00FFFF'>
</div>
```